# I have got AnyObject vehicle. need to access the values from vehicle object

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, viewcontroller

```
{
        "id": 144241,
        "name": "Teltonika Test 8",
        "vrn": "ML57CEU3",
        "make": "Ford",
        "model": "Focus",
        "year": null,
        "icon": "red_car",
        "fuelType": "Petrol",
        "odometer": null,
        "useCostMile": 77,
        "idleCostHour": 77,
        "taxDate": "2015-12-05",
        "motDate": "2015-12-05",
        "nextServiceDate": "2015-12-05",
        "createdAt": 1433237926000,
        "updatedAt": 1433237926000,
        "privateCostPerMile": 77,
        "idleAlertTime": 77,
        "repeatPtoAlertTime": null,
        "payload": 0,
        "notifyMileage": 77,
        "siteVehicleType": null,
        "realRoadSpeed": false,
        "customer": {
            "id": 13492
        },
        "depot": {
            "id": 13492
        },
        "vehicleType": null,
        "deviceConfiguration": {
            "id": 139973
        },
        "liveView": {
            "id": 144061,
            "gpsPosition": {
                "id": 9209187941,
                "latitude": 3216.882,
                "longitude": -9.45553,
                "speed": 25,
                "heading": 0,
                "dateTime": 1351400858000
            },
            "currentStatus": "moving",
            "creationTime": 1433237926000,
            "createdAt": 1433237926000,
            "updatedAt": 1433237926000,
            "clockMeters": 77,
            "lastState": null,
            "batteryPercent": null
        },
        "businessHours": [
            {
                "id": 189251
            }
        ],
        "driver": null,
        "imei": null
    },
```

I want to display lastState from liveview. I am not getting wrapping concepts in Swift programmming.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
var dict = vehicleObject as! [String: AnyObject]
var liveViewDict = dict["liveView"]! as! [String : AnyObject]
var lastState = liveViewDict["lastState"] as! String
```

Also, since this value is `null` and not nil, you'll have it check its value for `NSNull`.

Comment: vehicleLastState.text  = vehicle["liveView"]["lastState"] as! AnyObject is not working

Comment: need some training on swift programming

Comment: @Raj updated the code with Typecasting to `String`. If it still doesn't work, tell me what is the error that you get. And in console print the value from the line `liveViewDict["lastState"] as! String` and tell me its value.

Comment: thank you it is working. I need training in swift please, can you teach me

Comment: @Raj :D You should read the first chapter of `The Swift Programming Language` by `Apple`. It should get you started.